# Batch: search csv file for variable and return row values

Tags: batch-file, csv

I have a CSV file with users information in it. I am trying to create a simple batch that allows anyone to input a name or part of a name, or company and if it finds the results, displays it nicely.
The csv file has four columns: Name, Company, City, State
The name column does have a comma, but is already enclosed in double quotes.

[myfile.csv]

```
Name,Company,City,State
"Smith, John",ACME,Buffalo,NY
"Doe, Jane",Disney,Orlando,FL
```

[/myfile.csv]

[searchcsv.bat]

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set CSVFILE=myfile.csv

:HOME
cls
set column=""
echo ---- USER SEARCH TOOL ----
echo ---- By: Dimitri ----
echo.
echo     1  Search By Name
echo     2  Search By Company
echo     X  Close
echo.

Choice /C 12X /N /M "Please make a selection: "
echo.

IF ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO :EXIT
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO :SCHCOMP
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :SCHNAME

:SCHNAME
set column=lname
echo ---- Enter Last Name ----
set /p strsearch=
cls
GOTO :FINDIT

:SCHCOMP
set column=Company
echo ---- Enter Company -----
set /p strsearch=
cls
GOTO :FINDIT

:FINDIT
for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%A in (%CSVFILE%) do (
set inline=%%A
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=," %%1 in ("!inline!") do (
set lname=%%1&set fname=%%2&set comp=%%3&set cit=%%4&set stat=%%5
if %column% equ %strsearch% ( GOTO :SHOWRES ) ELSE ( GOTO :NFOUND )
)
)

:SHOWRES
echo Company: %comp%
echo Name: %lname%,%fname%
echo City: %cit%
echo State: %stat%
pause
GOTO :Home

:NFOUND
echo NOT FOUND Try AGAIN
pause
GOTO :HOME
```

[/searchcsv.bat]

I wish I could search by Last Name, First Name but because of the comma in the name, tends to mess things up.

Anyway, Hopefully someone can point out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for all the help.

-Dimitri

Comment: Does this absolutely have to be in batch (ie: homework)? or can a vbscript/powershell script be used?

Comment: vbscript can be used. I'm just not that familiar with vb script at the moment. Powershell is blocked in our environment, so that is out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set CSVFILE=myfile.csv

:HOME
cls
set column=""
echo ---- USER SEARCH TOOL ----
echo ---- By: Dimitri ----
echo.
echo     1  Search By Name
echo     2  Search By Company
echo     X  Close
echo.

Choice /C 12X /N /M "Please make a selection: "
echo.

IF ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO :EOF
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO  SCHCOMP
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO  SCHNAME

:SCHNAME
set column=lname
echo ---- Enter Last Name ----
set /p strsearch=
GOTO FINDIT

:SCHCOMP
set column=Company
echo ---- Enter Company -----
set /p strsearch=
GOTO FINDIT

:FINDIT
CLS
SET found=N
for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%A in (%CSVFILE%) do (
set inline=%%A
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=," %%a in ("!inline!") do (
set lname=%%~a&set fname=%%~b&set comp=%%~c&set cit=%%~d&set stat=%%~e
CALL SET fname=!fname:"=!
if %column% equ Company CALL :MATCH "%%~c"
if %column% equ lname CALL :MATCH "%%~a"
)
)
IF %found%==N echo NOT FOUND Try AGAIN
pause
GOTO :Home

:MATCH
SET matchto=%~1
CALL SET matchto=%%matchto:%strsearch%=%%
IF "%matchto%"==%1 GOTO :EOF 
SET found=Y

:SHOWRES
echo Company: %comp%
echo Name: %lname%,%fname%
echo City: %cit%
echo State: %stat%
GOTO :eof
```

Here's a revised routine. I'll not say it's bullet-proof...

First issue is that you can't use numerics as your metavariable (`%%x` in `for ...%%x`) - it must be an alphabetic, and is case-sensitive. (well- a few symbols work, too) - So - `%%a` and `%%A` above are different.

Next: your data, when tokenised against <kbd>,</kbd> may yield unbalanced quotes like `"Smith` and `Jane"`. These can cause batch conniptions. Normally, the cure is to assign the variable to `%%~x` where the <kbd>~</kbd> removes the enclosing quotes - BUT it only does that if the first character is <kbd>"</kbd> hence the requirement to "manually" strip the quotes on `lname`.

Next: a matter of data. You may wish to match exactly, but it's a pain having to type `Cholmondley-Snodgrass`. especially if you insist on a case-match. Also, how many `Smith`s are you likely to have in your data? For that matter, sometimes more than one person works for a company.

Hence, setting a flag `found` at the start of the search and setting it to another value if a hit is found will allow you to choose whether or not to show the fail message. `CALL`ing `MATCH` in the revised routine, passing either the company name or lastname as the first parameter means that you can simply match `strsearch` to the value passed. It's passed in quotes to cater for names like `di Maggio` which contains a space.

The match routine tries to replace `strsearch` within `matchto` with (the string after the <kbd>=</kbd> - which is empty. So `matchto` will be changed if a matching substring is found. Therefore, if it remains unchanged, there's no match, otherwise set the `found` flag and show the record data.

I have a personal aversion to the `goto :label` syntax. Certainly, it works. The only time it's necessary is `goto :EOF` which is predefined to mean 'end of this batch file`. The problem is that there **IS** a difference - not with`goto`but with`call`.`call :label`and`call label` are two different things. The first calls a routine **INTERNAL** to this batch file, while the second calls a separate batchfile with the name. Much easier if you only use the <kbd>:</kbd> when it's required. Quicker to type, too.

Comment: Worked great.. had to get rid of the 

    ECHO IF "%matchto%"==%1 GOTO :EOF

One last thing, lets say there is 3 companies, ACME-A, ACME-B, ACME-C, all three companies have different users, and I do a company search, and just search "ACME", is there a way to add something like if %comp% >1 echo more then one company... then list the companies found and have you select one from a list or something? Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 0):

Your code have several small errors:

- Below `:SCHCOMP` you `set column=Company`, but the variable that store the Company is named just `comp`, so previous line must be changed to `set column=comp`.
- In the assignment of the 5 values, you must note that the values assigned to `lname` and `fname` variables *include the quotes* because `delims=,`. You must eliminate the quotes with `%%~1` and `%%~2`.
- In the comparison for the searched values: `if %column% equ %strsearch% ( GOTO :SHOWRES ) ELSE ( GOTO :NFOUND )`, if the *first value* is not the searched value your code immediately go to NFOUND and the rest of values are not compared. You need to eliminate the ELSE part and rearrange the code.
- In the same comparison: `if %column% equ %strsearch% ...` "column" variable contain the *name* of the search variable ("lname" or "comp"), but you want not to compare such name, but the *value* of such variable, so an additional delayed expansion is required: `if /I "!%column%!" equ "%strsearch%" ...`. Also, it is convenient to enclose the comparing values in quotes and use /I switch.

Although it is not an error, I suggest you to NOT use digits in FOR command replaceable parameters. You should always use letters and preserve the digits for the Batch file replaceable parameters.

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set CSVFILE=myfile.csv

:HOME
cls
set column=""
echo ---- USER SEARCH TOOL ----
echo ---- By: Dimitri ----
echo.
echo     1  Search By Name
echo     2  Search By Company
echo     X  Close
echo.

Choice /C 12X /N /M "Please make a selection: "
echo.

IF ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO :EXIT
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO :SCHCOMP
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :SCHNAME

:SCHNAME
set column=lname
echo ---- Enter Last Name ----
set /p strsearch=
cls
GOTO :FINDIT

:SCHCOMP
set column=comp
echo ---- Enter Company -----
set /p strsearch=
cls
GOTO :FINDIT

:FINDIT
for /f "skip=1 tokens=*" %%A in (%CSVFILE%) do (
   set inline=%%A
   for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=," %%1 in ("!inline!") do (
      set "lname=%%~1" & set "fname=%%~2" & set "comp=%%3" & set "cit=%%4" & set "stat=%%5"
      if /I "!%column%!" equ "%strsearch%" GOTO :SHOWRES
   )
)

:NFOUND
echo NOT FOUND Try AGAIN
pause
GOTO :HOME

:SHOWRES
echo Company: %comp%
echo Name: %lname%,%fname%
echo City: %cit%
echo State: %stat%
pause
GOTO :Home

:EXIT
```